# SELECT * FROM user_clienti WHERE user_id = :user_id";

Tags: php, html, ajax, pdo

I try to make do when I can but now I need some help:
I have a problem with displaying a query, when I press on the button (view) I view the blank form without the values required by me
While everything else works (both ' Add ' and ' Edit '
post the code and image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2MdE.png)

```
    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'product_details')
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM user_clienti WHERE user_id = :user_id";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
    array(
            ':user_id'  =>  $_POST["user_id"]
        )
    );
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-boredered">
    ';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $status = '';
        if($row['user_status'] == 'Attivo')
        {
            $status = '<span class="label label-success">Attivo</span>';
        }
        else
        {
            $status = '<span class="label label-danger">Disattivo</span>';
        }
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>'.$row["user_nome"].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stato</td>
            <td>'.$status.'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
    $output .= '
        </table>
    </div>
    ';
    echo $output;
}
```

I do not recognize the id selected. If the query

```
"SELECT * FROM user_clienti WHERE user_id = ':user_id'";
```

delete

```
= ':user_id'
```

show me everything
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chnE1.png)

I also tried so but nothing

```
SELECT * FROM user_clienti WHERE user_id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."'
    ";
```

[We'll post the link to download the 3 file.php I can't place them here](https://files.fm/u/k24n299a)

help me thanks a lot

Comment: are you sure, when you do a `view` the code shown above gets executed? The thing is, a `view` should be a `GET` command and not a `POST` command. However apparently you are testing for a `POST` command in the first line of your code above...

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: I posted the 3 linked files if you want to directly control:(

Comment: I fixed it thanks a lot too